# Instantiate one View per Viewmodel (multiple Views of the same type)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, wpf-controls

Is there any way to instantiate one view per Viewmodel? I currently apply Views to their Viewmodels with

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CustomerViewModel}">
    <vw:CustomerView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

but as my task is to make views remember the selection of their focused TextBox I need my program to make one view per Viewmodel instead of just changing DataContext.

---

**I already searched two whole weeks for this and my question is just whether (and how) I can instantiate multiple Views of the same Type (and not how to remember TextBox selection) :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all suggestions, but I found the solution by myself. To anyone having similar problems; this link will help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460989/WPF-TabControl-Turning-Off-Tab-Virtualization

Answer (score 1):

The way I handle this is to make my ViewModel an input to the xaml in the code behind. For example:

```
public partial class AddMember : Window
{
    StructureGeneratorVM mainVM = null;
    public AddMember(object vm)
    {
        mainVM = (StructureGeneratorVM)vm;
        DataContext = mainVM;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then, when I open the window from the Base Window's VM I pass in `this` and then all the windows in my program are working on the same VM (which belongs to the original MainWindow)

Is this what you were asking?

Comment: The idea is good, but my question was about something different: My problem is that WPF always creates only one object of a view-type and then changes the DataContext when you switch to "another instance" of the view (how some people would expect it). If there was any dirty trick to change that my problem would be solved...

Comment: When you create "another instance" of the view, pass the datacontext along with the creation?

Comment: Yes, of course... but _how do I create another instance of a view?_  When applying Views to Viewmodels per DataTemplate as described above, only one View-object will be created and only the DataContext changes (while I want to create another View instead)

Comment: I see, So you're saying you don't want to share viewModels. you want each window to be working on an independent view model?

Comment: The Viewmodel is not the problem. I need _one View per ViewModel_. So each ViewModel should have its own View instance, and this View shold have its ViewModel as DataContext. The problem is that WPF ALWAYS makes only one object-instance of a View, and if there should be multiple instances of a view, e.g. in a TabControl, then it won't make another View when creating a new ViewModel (WPF knows how to associate Views with ViewModels because of the DataTemplate). _It just changes DataContext of the one View_ while you would expect there are multiple Views.

Comment: Oh okay. That makes sense. Is setting the data context xaml side a requirement for you? Like in my original answer if you have `MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel()` and then `DataContext = vm;` before `InitializeComponent();` then it will do what you're asking for. The only thing you'll lose is the inellisense type xaml side. Everything else should behave the way you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Your view-model should contain the state of the selection, which should be bound in your view. Then the `DataTemplate` will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I already tried that... My question was whether it is possible to instantiate multiple views... to be honest I don't see a reason why not to do it as it wouldn't even affect performance in a notable way I think

Comment: Sure, it's just quite roundabout and requires you to keep track of all the associations.